# Automatic Code Identation

Tags: matlab

I have a huge code and now for testing purpose I have to add that whole script into an infinite while loop is there any short way (without pressing space for each row) to add a space for indentation so the whole code is consider part of the one while loop ? Such as for example when we press ctrl +r it comments out the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> will automatically indent the file. Other wse you just select multiple row and use <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move them backwards and forwards.

For indentation is a must, however Matlab as a language does not care so it is not really a must to indent it. Additionally, you can just execute the code from the command line, say that you script or function is called `Umar`, then from the command line you just type `while 1, Umar; end`.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the code into [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).
Activate Column mode selection holding alt+shift and use the mouse to select the column of all the text you want to insert a space/tabulation/etc. and just insert it.
Final step is to copy back the code to matlab.

Matlab does not currently support column selection.

Comment: What do you mean by 'column selection'?

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has the option to select all your code, then press the right click and select smart indent button.

If you like to use shortcuts, just type the combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select all) followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (smart indent)